# How can I get calculated of each of three elements in row can have 300px width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

Im trying to make "my own framework" using flexbox. The most headache of flexbox when in row an odd number of element: 3, 5 , 7. So I want to solve it using js/jq. For example if width of element is 300px or less - element becomes 100% of width. I'm using jq code:

```
function check() {
  var window = $(document).outerWidth();
  var width = $('.one-third').outerWidth();

  if ( width < 300 ) {
  $('.one-third').addClass('one-third-full')
   }

  else {
    $('.one-third').removeClass('one-third-full')
  }

  $('.one-third').text(width)

}
```

But the issue is when the function set the width of element to 100% according to CSS rule, the script recalculates according to its IF statement and the elements start to blink. Can anyone help me to solve this?
The code is in snippet.

```js
function check() {
  var window = $(document).outerWidth();
  var width = $('.one-third').outerWidth();
  
  if ( width < 300 ) {
  $('.one-third').addClass('one-third-full')
   }
  
  else {
    $('.one-third').removeClass('one-third-full')
  }
  
  $('.one-third').text(width)
 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  check()
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  check()
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #C38D94;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}


.fbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
.one-half:after, .one-third:after, .one-four:after, .one-five:after, .one-six:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.one-half:after {
  content: '2';
}
.one-third:after {
  content: '3';
}
.one-four:after {
  content: '4';
}
.one-five:after {
  content: '5';
}
.one-six:after {
  content: '6';
}
.one-half, .one-third, .one-four, .one-five, .one-six{
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #565676;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
.one-half {
  flex: 1 calc(50% - 4px); 
  min-width: 300px;
  }

.one-third {
  flex: 1 calc(30% - 4px);
  
}
.one-four {
  flex: 1 calc(25% - 4px);
  
}
.one-five {
  flex: 1 calc(20% - 4px);
  
}

.one-six {
  flex: 1 calc(15% - 4px);
  
}
.one-third-full {
flex: 1 100%;
}

.to-column {
  flex-flow: column
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fbox dns">   
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div> 
</div> 


<div class="fbox"> 
  <div class="one-half"></div>
  <div class="one-half"></div>
</div>
  
 <div class="fbox">  
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div> 
</div> 
   
<div class="fbox"> 
<div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
</div>
  
  <div class="fbox"> 
  
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox"> 
  <div class="one-half"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
</div>
  
  <div class="fbox"> 
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-half"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox"> 
<div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="truth"></div>
```

Comment: sorry if its only me not to get you.

Comment: Three elements in row have more then 300px,if they less of 300px so they get 100% of width. If each of the element can have >300px they are three in row. Resize the width of window to get the issue. Codepen example: http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/OyeGJW

Comment: In which size you are getting problem? i have resized and works fine for me?

Comment: I can see no issue. May be you're after to trigger resize?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi  When you squeeze the window the elements start to blink.

Comment: yes but on widow resize it will make its width as per your condition so it looks like blinking.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need any JavaScript/jQuery code for this.
In this case, just use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to handle the resizing.

Knowing the items should be `100%` wide when the screen is less then `900px` wide (`900px / 3 = 300px`), you can use a media query defining the width.

**Fiddle** (containing full example): http://jsfiddle.net/gfsb82p9/

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .one-third {
    flex: 1 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to keep using the jQuery way, you need to do the width check on the window and not on the element since the element width goes above 300 px when you add the class in.

See amended code below.

```js
function check() {
  var windowWidth = $('body').outerWidth();
  var width = $('.one-third').outerWidth();

  if (windowWidth < 900) {
    console.log(windowWidth);
    if ($('.one-third').hasClass('one-third-full') != true) {
      $('.one-third').addClass('one-third-full');
    }
  } else {
    console.log(width);
    if ($('.one-third').hasClass('one-third-full')) {
      $('.one-third').removeClass('one-third-full');
    }
  }

  $('.one-third').text(width)

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  check()
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  check()
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #C38D94;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
}
.fbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.one-half:after,
.one-third:after,
.one-four:after,
.one-five:after,
.one-six:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.one-half:after {
  content: '2';
}
.one-third:after {
  content: '3';
}
.one-four:after {
  content: '4';
}
.one-five:after {
  content: '5';
}
.one-six:after {
  content: '6';
}
.one-half,
.one-third,
.one-four,
.one-five,
.one-six {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #565676;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.one-half {
  flex: 1 calc(50% - 4px);
  min-width: 300px;
}
.one-third {
  flex: 1 calc(30% - 4px);
}
.one-four {
  flex: 1 calc(25% - 4px);
}
.one-five {
  flex: 1 calc(20% - 4px);
}
.one-six {
  flex: 1 calc(15% - 4px);
}
.one-third-full {
  flex: 1 100%;
}
.to-column {
  flex-flow: column
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fbox dns">
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
</div>


<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-half"></div>
  <div class="one-half"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">

  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-half"></div>
  <div class="one-five"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-third"></div>
  <div class="one-half"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
  <div class="one-four"></div>
</div>

<div class="fbox">
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
  <div class="one-six"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="truth"></div>
```